# What is the origin and meaning of the phrase- some good bones

Tags: expressions, idioms, figurative

Where does the expression ‘some good bones’ come from, and how is it primarily used?

Comment: Where did you hear the expression? When someone says that a house has good bones they may mean that it is structurally sound, or they may mean the architecture (floor plan, etc.) is good. In those cases the "some" in "some good bones" could be an intensifier, or could be indicating that only part of the house is good, depends on tone.